# xmlHttpRequest check for changes in mysql database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm making an auction site like BidRivals and in my website the auction script works but the code is very poor and by that i mean that i have to automatically refresh the page every 5 seconds so that the user can see if there are new bids to the products.

I'm trying to optimize my code so that the page only refreshes if there are new bids, otherwise it doesn't.

I was told to use xmlHttpRequest but i never used it before and know how that works.
Already went to w3schools did some research but i found nothing to my case.

Any ideas?

Comment: Read some basic tutorials on AJAX, and the [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) Javascript library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much better approach than using `XMLHttpRequest` would be to use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

It's better because jQuery removes most of the burden of cross-platform compatibility from the developer.  Also, jQuery is a very useful library for doing many common things in javascript, and as such, is very helpful to know.

*On some/many browsers, jQuery's Ajax methods are implemented using `XMLHttpRequest`.*

Comment: thanks, do you know where i can get some source code so i can start to work with? cause jQuery's ajax is also a language that i dont know and it would be great if i could get some source to work with :s

Comment: The link given in the post contains many examples.  Here it is again in case you didn't notice it:  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: oh thanks, i new to this website so i didn't noticed, thanks again :)

Comment: doesn't jquery always use hmlhttprequest for ajax?

Comment: @yes123 -- no.  See `ActiveXObject`.

Answer (score 0):

Using xmlHttpRequest is a good Idea. With this technique you can send an asyncronous request to the server, without reloading the page. You could then change the HTML, for example fetch new HTML from the Server and replace a `<div>` in your Site.
I would recommend to use a Java Script library like JQuery that handles different Browser implementations for you. JQuery provides easy functions for loading content asyncronously.

With this, you could avoid refreshing the Page entirely, and only reload the content. Or you could make the server send a changed flag back, and then decide if to reload the page with Java Script.